# Why doesn't my code work on my PC, but does on others?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

When I run this code it asks me for inputs. But when I input for instance `y`, it gives me an "objectnotfound error", and when I input `h`, it gives me some list which is longer than the entirety of the code.

I tried sending this code to someone else in the Python [Discord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discord_(software)) channel and it seemed like it worked for them.

```py
def average() -> float:
    nums = []
    while True:
        try:
            nums.append(float(input('')))
        except ValueError:
            return sum(nums) / len(nums)
```

When I input `y`:

```
PS C:\Users\NPC> 7
7
PS C:\Users\NPC> 5
5
PS C:\Users\NPC> 1
1
PS C:\Users\NPC> 51.56
51,56
PS C:\Users\NPC> y
y : The term 'y' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ y
+ ~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (y:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

When I input `h`:

```
PS C:\Users\NPC> 6
6
PS C:\Users\NPC> 62.32
62,32
PS C:\Users\NPC> 5123.412
5123,412
PS C:\Users\NPC> h

  Id CommandLine
  -- -----------
   1 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   2 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   3 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   4 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   5 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   6 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
   7 4
   8 5
   9 6
  10 y
  11 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  12 6
  13 5
  14 34
  15 h
  16 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  17 y
  18 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  19 5
  20 2
  21 5
  22 d
  23 5
  24 2
  25 5
  26 print(nums)
  27 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  28 4
  29 5
  30 6
  31 y
  32 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  33 7
  34 5
  35 1
  36 51.56
  37 y
  38 & C:/Users/NPC/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe "c:/Users/NPC/Desktop/python projects/arithm...
  39 6
  40 62.32
  41 5123.412
```

I'm using the latest 32-bit release of Visual Studio Code on a 32-bit Windows 10 Pro system. I also tried that code in Python [IDLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE), but this didn't seem to work as well.

Comment: It looks like you're typing input directly into PowerShell, not into your code. How are you trying to run your script?

Comment: @Chris i just press run the code in vsc then input in the terminal but it is somehow input dependent(?) when i input y it gives me object not found when i input h it gives me a weird list

Comment: What does "press run the code" mean?

Comment: @Chris the green triangle that runs the code in the top right of the screen

Comment: Huh. I've never used that button. In any case, is there more code that you're not showing us? The code here just defines a function, it doesn't run it. If you're showing us all the code it would make sense that it runs an then exits without asking for any input.

Comment: @Chris nope, this is the entire code, it asks for inputs but the problem is the output, it is supposed to give an output when a non-float non-integer input has been inputted(?)

Comment: No, the problem is the input. I'll add an answer.

Comment: There is nothing _weird_  on that list as `h` is simply powershell alias for `Get-History`. See `Get-Alias h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining a function but not calling it, so when you run your code it finishes running before you type anything. Your input it being sent directly to PowerShell, not to your program.

Add this to the bottom of your script:

```py
average()
```

As others have pointed out, in your `except` branch you `return` your result instead of `print`ing it. You probably want to `print(sum(nums) / len(nums))` instead.

I also strongly suggest adding a text prompt to more easily distinguish between your program and your shell, e.g.

```py
float(input('Please enter a number: '))
```

Comment: yeah so i fixed the code, it now runs but doesnt function the way it was intended: ```def average() -> float:
    nums = []
    while True:
        try:
            nums.append(float(input('')))
        except ValueError:
            return sum(nums) / len(nums)
average()``` it now just takes inputs and when i input a non-float it just doesnt do anything no output

Comment: the function `average()` returns the calculated value, so when calling the function save the result into a variable or print the returned value, otherwise the calculations will be in vain. Try using `print(average())`

Comment: @Supremayro420 That's because you did not ask it to have an output... use `print`.